# Possible Kafka streaming without CDC?

Tags: database, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, cdc

I'm working on a project at work. I'm curious if it is possible to implement Kafka on a database without CDC. (CDC isn't turned on all the time on it)
Can't find any resources online that discuss other options. Is it possible to feed the data directly into kafka? For instance write C# code to read data base and then plug into Kafka which acts as the connector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a watch of this, it explains everything :-)

https://www.confluent.io/kafka-summit-ny19/no-more-silos-integrating-db-into-apache-kafka

tl;dr : You *could* write some code, but the question is really *should* you write some code :) Almost certainly not. You can use "proper" CDC to get events from the transaction log, or you can use 'query-based CDC' with the JDBC Source connector to just poll new records. The pros and cons of each are discussed in the above talk.

Answer (score 3):

You can, but **should not**. Thinking as CDC as another piece of software, and of course, you can write similar software like that. There are many tricky things you need to handle:

- You should read data from database logs (binlog in MySQL, oplog in MongoDB ...) So you must understand the format of logs of each database vendors you want to export.
- Maintain persistent data. Let say you write to Kafka a list of data that in one transaction. What will happen when you write at the middle steps and something wrong happened? You must retry. Otherwise, another part of your system read data from Kafka will see the partial data.
  ...

There are many reasons behind that this is the only theoretical solution. This is a [great blog](http://martin.kleppmann.com/2015/04/23/bottled-water-real-time-postgresql-kafka.html) from one guy with very experienced in distributed database discussed writing a custom CDC into Postgres or any database vendor in general.