# Old SQL Server DB without CDC feature streaming ingest to Kafka

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka, cdc

I would like to have a SQL Server DB as a source into Kafka.

However, my **SQL Server version is old (2012 Standard)** and **does not have the CDC feature**, what are my options?

The 2 ways I've seen, from the Kafka documentation and blogposts, are to use the Debezium connector or the JDBC Connector. The content I read was from a 2018 post and so I wanted to check, now in 2022, if there are any new options that I'm missing.

Given the situation (SQL Server 2012), here are the choices I could think of:

1. Upgrade the DB to a later version, enable CDC, and work with the Debezium SQL Server Kafka Connect Source connector in true CDC
2. use the Confluent JDBC source connector

Are these the only 2 *good* options even in 2022?
(By good I mean please exclude telling me to write your own query-based CDC code).

Is the decision really just between:

- ideal: I **can upgrade the DB** to a later SQL Server Version with CDC: then enable CDC and use the Debezium connector
- not so ideal: I **cannot upgrade the DB**, no choice but to use the JDBC Source Connector
  ?

p.s I have referred to and read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56245778/possible-kafka-streaming-without-cdc) but that was from 2019 and also I wanted to know if *upgrading and then* using Debezium is a good idea

Comment: FYI, CDC has been a thing since SQL Server 2008. Even before 2008 R2.

Comment: The first question you should answer is what do you *need* in terms of data to capture? There are two approaches, termed "log based CDC" and "query based CDC". Each has pros and cons. [This talk](https://rmoff.dev/no-more-silos) covers both. Once you've settled on that it will help inform your path with regards to using Debezium, or perhaps make do with the JDBC Source connector. Hope that helps.

Comment: Other than there being other vendors like Attunity, for example, not much as changed between the recommendations of CDC or JDBC in only 4 years

Comment: @AlwaysLearning ok, I mean SQL Server 2012 Standard, that has no CDC